# Using dynamic variables in Ansible variable names

Tags: ansible

In the scope of a larger project I would like to use dynamic variables within Ansible variable names. This way, I hope to modularize my code by reusing playbook tasks with different variables based on specific settings.

In order to demonstrate, I created a little ansible project with following structure:

```
├── ansible.cfg
├── debug.yml
├── group_vars
│   └── custom
│       ├── myvar1.yml
│       └── myvar2.yml
├── inventory
└── playbooks
    └── main.yml
```

The group variables are both ansible dictionaries:

```
# Group var 1
---
myvar_1_dict:
  myvar_1_subelement:
    myvar_1_key: "myvar_1_value"
```

and

```
# Group var 2
---
myvar_2_dict:
  myvar_2_subelement:
    myvar_2_key: "myvar_1"
```

The main.yml playbook executes debug tasks:

```
# Playbook main
---
- hosts: myinventory
  connection: local
  vars:
    - play_var: "{{ myvar_2_dict.myvar_2_subelement.myvar_2_key }}"
  
  tasks:
  - name: Debug play_var
    debug:
      msg: "play_var value: {{ play_var }}"
      
  - name: Debug myvar_1_dict
    debug:
      msg: "myvar_1_dict value: {{ myvar_1_dict.myvar_1_subelement.myvar_1_key }}"
      
  - name: Debug dynamic variable 1
    debug:
      msg: "dynamic variable: {{ {{ play_var }}_dict.myvar_1_subelement.myvar_1_key }}"
      
  - name: Debug dynamic variable 2
    debug:
      msg: "dynamic variable: {{ {{ myvar_2_dict.myvar_2_subelement.myvar_2_key }}_dict.myvar_1_subelement.myvar_1_key }}"
```

The last two debug tasks throw an error. It seems I am unable to set the dynamic variable name properly. The error output is as follows:

```
PLAY [myinventory] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [local]

TASK [Debug play_var] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": "play_var value: myvar_1"
}

TASK [Debug myvar_1_dict] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [local] => {
    "msg": "myvar_1_dict value: myvar_1_value"
}

TASK [Debug dynamic variable 1] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [local]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: dynamic variable: {{ {{ play_var }}_dict.myvar_1_subelement.myvar_1_key }}. expected token ':', got '}'"}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
local                      : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I tried various notations as well as different approaches with e.g. set_facts but was unable to get my head around setting the dynamic variable correctly.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to resolve a variable dynamically meaning e.g. {{ {{ play_var }}_dict.myvar_1_subelement.myvar_1_key }} should be resolved to diffferent variables based on the value of {{ play_var }}, in this example it should resolve to {{ myvar_1_dict.myvar_1_subelement.myvar_1_key }}

Any approaches on how to do this?